# Embedded Linux project - finding supported peripherals

Tags: embedded, linux

We're starting an embedded board project.  We're exploring using embedded Linux and would like to select peripherals with working Linux drivers.

My question - for different subsystems (ethernet, memory, storage, etc) how do I determine what chips are supported, or if I had a chip - the KSZ8463 for example (http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/KSZ8463) how do I determine if it has linux driver support?

I suppose that I could look in the device tree and grep for things, but would KSZ8463 be presented as KSZ84xx or some other variant.  Things start getting more complicated quickly with the compatible driver support mechanism

I did see the Linux Kernel Device Database (LKDDb at https://cateee.net/lkddb/) but it doesn't seem to have been updated since 2007.

Is it possible to either get a complete list of supported chips for a given subsystem, or see if a given chip (the KSZ8463 for example) has an explicit driver or is supported via a compatible driver?

configuring a kernel for my arch with `make menuconfig` as suggested by @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams provides a lot of information, but there's not always a list of specific devices or families.

As an example, this is the configuration for ethernet phy device support
[image: network device support > phy device support]

Does that mean all microchip ethernet chips are supported, but TI only supports the DP83848?  Is there a way to find the actual known supported microchip ethernet chips (or any other chip where the description is as vague or "most devices supported"

Comment: Did you try running `make menuconfig` against the appropriate arch?

Comment: KSZ8463 looks like it's primarily a network device, not a peripheral. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @duskwuff: Sometimes the peripheral you run is connected over SPI or I2C instead of USB or PCIE.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ah, I didn't spot the SPI (configuration?) interface on that part. That makes more sense.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - no, I did not.  That's a good suggestion, I can try doing that.  I'm thinking that `make menuconfig` could work well enough for me so if you make that an answer, I'll accept it once I've created the menu config that and evaluated the result. Thanks!

Comment: Pressing "H" in menuconfig will give you a bit more information if available.

Comment: The lkddb is updated **automatically** since 2007. Last update of their database was from October 2017. Their API and web page system hasn't been updated since 2007 (which seems actually a good thing.)

Comment: The answer is, read the source code of the drivers which may match, check if the device is mentioned there and if it's not, email the maintainer listed in the file or that of the subsystem.

Comment: Realistically, if you're asking this question, you should probably for the present stick to remixing combinations of parts you've already seen used on similar embedded Linux boards, or those you have a thorough enough understanding of that you're prepared to write drivers yourself.

Comment: @Janka, that's backward from what I want.  I'd like to have a list of known-supported devices to start my search for one that matches our parameters rather than the much larger list of maybe-has-driver-need-check devices.  Agree on your comments on lkddb, I obviously missed the "generated in 2017" part in the footer of the search page.

Answer (score 1):

Actually searching the source for a string is a feasible way - Linux on ARM uses device tree and that needs a compatible string. Run `grep -Rni device` in the root source directory and look through the results. For example look at [line 1283 of sc16is7xx.c](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.3/source/drivers/tty/serial/sc16is7xx.c#L1283) - there is a table listing all supported devices.

If a full name doesnt come up try removing the last character or two - thats up to your discretion since it depends on the particular device and the naming scheme of that device family.